# Heroku migration error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, devise, migration

I am currently pushing a rails 3.2 app with ruby 2.0 to heroku.  I have successfully pushed the code to the new heroku server, and am now trying to migrate the DB, then seed it.

When I run the command

```
$ heroku run rake:db:migrate
```

I get the error:

```
Running `rake db:migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.8854
Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL
Migrating to CreateRoutines (20130720183354)
Migrating to CreateExercises (20130720183503)
Migrating to CreateLifts (20130720183601)
Migrating to CreateInfos (20130723010806)
Migrating to AddUserIdToRoutine (20130808142746)
Migrating to AddBodyweighToRoutine (20130810164534)
Migrating to AddDeviseToUsers (20131003183650)
==  AddDeviseToUsers: migrating ===============================================
-- change_table(:users)
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
: ALTER TABLE "users" ADD COLUMN "email" character varying(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:650:in `exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:650:in `block in execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:280:in `block in log'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:275:in `log'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:649:in `execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1022:in `add_column'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:479:in `block in string'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:468:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:468:in `string'
/app/db/migrate/20131003183650_add_devise_to_users.rb:5:in `block in up'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:243:in `change_table'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:466:in `block in method_missing'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:438:in `block in say_with_time'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:438:in `say_with_time'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:458:in `method_missing'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:334:in `method_missing'
/app/db/migrate/20131003183650_add_devise_to_users.rb:3:in `up'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:370:in `up'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:410:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:410:in `block in migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:129:in `with_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:389:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:528:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:720:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:775:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:775:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in `transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:775:in `ddl_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:719:in `block in migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:700:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:700:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:570:in `up'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:551:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:193:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Is this something that has to do with Devise?  Not sure what to do here.

Also some respondents have been asking if I have a users table:<.br>

```
create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at",                             :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                             :null => false
    t.string   "email",                  :default => "", :null => false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     :default => "", :null => false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          :default => 0
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "provider"
    t.string   "uid"
  end
```

Comment: Do you have a migration to created users table?

Comment: try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16974995/heroku-production-error-pgerror-error-relation-users-already-exists-error?rq=1)

Comment: I don't have a migration that's specifically for a users table, it looks like Devise did that for me in the migration that is causing the error.  This all works locally.  And I do have a user model.

Answer (score 0):

The error means you are trying to change the table `users`, but the table does not exist.

You should have created the table as part of another migration or, check the documentation of the devise installation. I'm quite sure there are instructions to create the necessary table instead of change it.

I gave a quick look [at the documentation](http://devise.plataformatec.com.br/#getting-started/configuring-models), and I believe the procedure is described in the "Getting started" section around the command

```
rails generate devise MODEL
```

Comment: I do have a user model.  This model was created when I used Devise.

Comment: The issue is not the model, but the table. You have no `users` table in your database. May be you have a model in the /models folder, but this will not create the corresponding table in the database.

Comment: In the rails console I can see all of my users.  Wouldn't this mean I have a user table?

Comment: In the Rails console locally or at Heroku?

Comment: Locally in the console

Comment: Then, again, it means that in the remote database you don't have such table. You probably never created it on the remote database.